What is the error in the regexSubstitution value in rules.json?
I want to make an extension that redirects all YouTube Shorts videos to the standard "watch" YouTube video. So I need to replace the shorts by watch in the URL and maintain everything after the shorts/.
When trying to load (unpacked) my extension on the browser, I get the following error:

rules.json: Rule with id 1 specifies an incorrect value for the "action.redirect.regexSubstitution" key.
Could not load manifest.

Here is my rules.json:
[
    { "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
      "condition": {
        "regexFilter": "^https://www\\.youtube\\.com/shorts/(.*)",
        "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
      },
      "action": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "redirect": {
          "regexSubstitution": "https://www\\.youtube\\.com/watch/\\1" 
        }
      }
    }
  ]

As I understand, \\1 is a backreference to the capture group (.*) in the regexFilter. I tried removing that part so that regexSubstitution would just be "https://www\\.youtube\\.com/watch/" and I still got the same error.

regexSubstitution doesn't support escape characters except for numbered groups. Replace all \\. with ., so it becomes https://www.youtube.com/watch/\\1. P.S. This rule won't work when navigating inside the site, because it's a SPA, so you'll need a content script with a click event listener.
